# Need help using VPDexpress.exe to build Windows Phone 7 from command line

Tags: windows-phone-7, jenkins, visual-studio-express

I have a question regarding building for Windows Phone 7 via command line, using VPDexpress.exe

I'm calling VPDexpress via the following:

VPDexpress.exe solutions_file.sln" /build "Release" /log "C:\build_log.txt"

Question:  How can I get feedback about the build process (warnings/failures etc.) via the command line, identical to what I get in Visual Studio Express?  How can I verify that /build "Release" is actually building the correct configuration?

Comment: Does anyone with direct experience building for WP7 with Visual Studio Express know the answer to the above?  I'm hoping to get this running with Hudson/Jenkins, I'm having issues verifying that it builds properly/identical to how it builds with the gui.  Building for Windows Phone, Release.  Trying to get some kind of feedback (warnings/errors etc.)

Answer (score 0):

After that command, you can just do `cat C:\build_log.txt` and see the build output.

Comment: Does this log show the same info that Visual Studio Express's GUI shows?

Comment: I'd say yes, but frankly I'm not sure... unfortunately for this particular case, I use VS professional!